# SQL Creating a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to create a table called "Receita" which contains a foreign key from a table called Farmaco

but for reason i keep getting this error and im not really picking it up

```
"There is already an object named 'Farmaco' in the database."
```

heres the cod where i create both tables

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects
                where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Receita]'))

begin
    CREATE TABLE Receita(
        IDReceita int NOT NULL
            CHECK(IDReceita>0),
        IDFarmaco int,

    CONSTRAINT PK_IDReceita PRIMARY KEY (IDReceita),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IDFarmaco FOREIGN KEY (IDFarmaco)
        REFERENCES Farmaco (IDFarmaco)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
end
```

and

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects
                where id=object_id(N'[dbo.Farmaco]'))
begin
    CREATE TABLE Farmaco(
        IDFarmaco int NOT NULL
        CHECK(IDFarmaco>0),
        IDMedico int,
        Tipo varchar(50)

    CONSTRAINT PK_IDFarmaco PRIMARY KEY (IDFarmaco),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IDMedico7 FOREIGN KEY (IDMedico)
        REFERENCES Médico (IDMedico)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
end
```

Thank you

Comment: An object does not need to be a table.

Comment: The thing is: i've done like 5 or 6 tables with the same code (with differente names ofc) and it worked well, when i was doing this one the bug appeared and i cant figure out whats wrong

Comment: You could select from sysobjects to find what 'Farmaco' is....

Comment: Can't confirm, but one thing I notice is that you check for dbo.Farmaco but create Farmaco. It is possible that Farmaco (or whatever) appears under another namespace - which would cause your issue, also 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'<TableName>') is technically better as you could have another object named 'Farmaco' - however unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like SteveJ mentioned there's a mistake here:

```
if not exists (
    select * from dbo.sysobjects where id=object_id(N'[dbo.Farmaco]')
)
```

, which should be

```
if not exists (
    select * from dbo.sysobjects where id=object_id(N'[dbo].[Farmaco]')
)
```

Look at brackets around the table name!

So the problem is that in the second script `if` condition is always true even when Farmaco table exists. Because of that you keep getting error message.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen your snippet, you have to create table "dbo.Farmaco" first before "dbo.Receita" thats only way you can reference dbo.Farmaco table as foreign key in 
dbo.Receita table.

Hope this will help you.